# Renaming a variable with a hyphen in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi guys so I have an issue with renaming a column within my data set that contains a hyphen. The column is called Sci-Fi. I havent created the data myself, it was imported. Since these characters cannot be used in SAS I have to rename the column.
I used the rename syntax but I keep getting errors.

```
data temp_videogamedata;
  rename "Sci-Fi"=Sci_fi;
run;
```

Error: 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Im just a beginner in SAS and not sure how to go about this issue.
Can anyone help.

Comment: Use a **name literal** by placing an `N` character directly after the quoted variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "imported" the variable then you probably can prevent it from being created with an invalid name to begin with by making sure you have the system option VALIDVARNAME set to the value V7 before doing the import.

```
options validvarname=v7;
proc import .... ;
run;
```

Otherwise to reference a variable with a non-valid name you have to use a name literal. Which like DATE or TIME literals is a quoted string with a letter after the closing quote.  For a name literal you use the letter n, for Name.

```
data temp_videogamedata;
  set videogamedata;
  rename "Sci-Fi"n=Sci_fi;
run;
```